# Why cannot I call the app when I save the R script as app.R into the working directory?

Tags: r, shiny

First of all I set my working directory as following

```
setwd("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/App-1")
```

Then I can call the app with the following code:

```
runApp("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/App-1")
```

But I cannot call the app via :

```
runApp("App-1")
```

The script in the directory is named  as "app.R" but it appears in the directory as "app".

Whereas, in the R webpage it says if I create a new directory named App-1 it should have worked. But It does not. Many thanks.

Comment: try `shiny::runApp(getwd())`, there's no `App-1` directory in WD = `C:/Users/asus/Desktop/App-1`

Comment: Or `runApp(".")`

Comment: But how can I make it work using runApp(App-1). Why is not it "App-1" but "."? Many thanks.

Comment: I did not understand your comment @waldi

Comment: You're trying to open : `C:/Users/asus/Desktop/App-1/App-1`

Comment: now my wd is "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Rshiney" and inside the file the app appears as "app". When I run   ´´´runApp("App-1")´´´ still it does not open

Comment: Is App-1 a directory as it is supposed to be?

Comment: In the webpage it says "Create a new directory named App-1 in your working directory. Then copy and paste the app.R script above into your directory (the scripts from Hello Shiny)." Then it says "Launch your app by running runApp("App-1")"  I tried to do that. But I could not for no reason.

Comment: There is a reason: you're changing working directories (with `setwd()`). The instructions above assume that the working directory *contains* `App-1`, not that the working directory *is* `App-1` itself.